# How to consume Odata service method in c# or in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have to consume a method defined in the Odata Service. I am very new to OData service and really do not know how to consume it. Below is the method which is defined in the Odata service.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("GetEmpsByPinAndCityName")]
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult GetEmpsByPinAndCityName(int pincode, string cityName)
{
    var result = this.context.EmpSets.Where(x => x.PinCode == pincode & x.CityName == cityName).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

So can anyone please explain how I can consume it in C# or in Jquery.

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support
has some information that you can refer to first.

Answer (score 1):

This might help - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app

For JavaScript client breeze can be used http://www.getbreezenow.com/